# Serializing an object with variations of the same property

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a method with which I can serialize an object.

for example.

```
List<Titles> lstCrmTitleSer = new List<Titles>();
```

I loop through a collection of string titles and I add it to the list of the type Titles to serialize them.

```
foreach (var ls in lstCrmTitles)
{
    Titles t = new Titles();

    t.title = ls;
    lstCrmTitleSer.Add(t);
}
```

This is my object and method with which I serialize the object.

```
static public void SerializeToXMLCollection(List<Titles> trainingTitles)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Titles>));
    string path = string.Concat(@"C:\Users\Arian\Desktop\Titles.xml");
    Console.WriteLine(path);
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path);
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, trainingTitles);
    textWriter.Close();
}

public string title { get; set; }
```

The thing is my Xml file is displayed as follow

```
<Titles>
      <title>title a</title>
</Titles>
<Titles>
      <title>title b</title>
</Titles>   
<Titles>
      <title>title c</title>
</Titles>
```

What I would like if for my xml to be displayed as follow

```
<Titles>
       <title>title a</title>
       <title>title b</title>
       <title>title c</title>
</Titles>
```

How can I tweak my code to achieve the above reult?

Comment: You could switch to [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). Would that work?

Comment: do note that your suggestion would mean that you cannot deserialize it. Is that an issue for you?

Comment: Deserializing is just as easy.. I have an extension for that too if you want it

Comment: See my edited answer below.. have added deserialization extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. Here's a generic extension method for you to use.. I wrote it a few years back and it will serialize anything:

```
/// <summary>
/// <para>Serializes the specified System.Object and writes the XML document</para>
/// <para>to the specified file.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">This item's type</typeparam>
/// <param name="item">This item</param>
/// <param name="fileName">The file to which you want to write.</param>
/// <returns>true if successful, otherwise false.</returns>
public static bool XmlSerialize<T>(this T item, string fileName)
{
    return item.XmlSerialize(fileName, true);
}

/// <summary>
/// <para>Serializes the specified System.Object and writes the XML document</para>
/// <para>to the specified file.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">This item's type</typeparam>
/// <param name="item">This item</param>
/// <param name="fileName">The file to which you want to write.</param>
/// <param name="removeNamespaces">
///     <para>Specify whether to remove xml namespaces.</para>para>
///     <para>If your object has any XmlInclude attributes, then set this to false</para>
/// </param>
/// <returns>true if successful, otherwise false.</returns>
public static bool XmlSerialize<T>(this T item, string fileName, bool removeNamespaces)
{
    object locker = new object();

    XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    xmlns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

    lock (locker)
    {
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileName, settings))
        {
            if (removeNamespaces)
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, item, xmlns);
            }
            else { xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, item); }

            writer.Close();
        }
    }

    return true;
}

/// <summary>
/// Serializes the specified System.Object and returns the serialized XML
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">This item's type</typeparam>
/// <param name="item">This item</param>
/// <param name="removeNamespaces">
///     <para>Specify whether to remove xml namespaces.</para>para>
///     <para>If your object has any XmlInclude attributes, then set this to false</para>
/// </param>
/// <returns>Serialized XML for specified System.Object</returns>
public static string XmlSerialize<T>(this T item, bool removeNamespaces = true)
{
    object locker = new object();
    XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    xmlns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

    lock (locker)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder))
        {
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings))
            {
                if (removeNamespaces)
                {
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, item, xmlns);
                }
                else { xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, item); }

                return stringBuilder.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second. Use it like this:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new MyObject();
        list.Titles.Add("title1");
        list.Titles.Add("title2");
        list.Titles.Add("title3");

        string serialized = list.XmlSerialize();

        //obviously here you would save to disk or whatever
        Console.WriteLine(serialized);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

[XmlRoot("Titles")]
public class MyObject
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public List<string> Titles { get; set; }

    public MyObject()
    {
        Titles = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Thirdly.. that code is just nasty. Even with the above suggestion, I still think you need to do some serious refactoring.

Good luck

**BONUS**

Extension for deseralizing a string to your type:

```
/// <summary>
/// Deserializes the XML data contained by the specified System.String
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of System.Object to be deserialized</typeparam>
/// <param name="s">The System.String containing XML data</param>
/// <returns>The System.Object being deserialized.</returns>
public static T XmlDeserialize<T>(this string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    var locker = new object();
    var stringReader = new StringReader(s);
    var reader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader);
    try
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        lock (locker)
        {
            var item = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
            return item;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var myObject = someSerializedString.XmlDeserialize<MyObject>()
```

Comment: why should he use your extension method? I don't see the profit with that. Also, the OP doesn't seem to have any `MyObject` class. Where did that come from? Your code differs very much from the OPs. Could you expand on what "code is looking nasty" and what the OP could do to make it not look nasty?

Comment: I called it MyObject because I dont know what the OP wants to call that class.. I tried Titles but the compiler threw an error for the reason that you can't have a property names the same as the class itself. I will leave it to the OP to change as he sees fit.

Comment: And he doesn;t have to use my extension method.. but what's the problem with it? It works for that and will also save him the trouble of needing to keep writing it ad-hoc everywhere for whatever other classes he may wish to serialize in future.. I have been using that for years and never needed anything else. What are you making a fuss about?